# How to update the Camera Position by using flutter_map plugin in flutter App

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is the code of Flutter Map

```
void showFlutterMap(){
  return new FlutterMap(
    options: new MapOptions(
      center: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
      zoom: 13.0,
    ),
    layers: [
      new TileLayerOptions(
        urlTemplate: "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/"
            "{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token={accessToken}",
        additionalOptions: {
          'accessToken': '<PUT_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE>',
          'id': 'mapbox.streets',
        },
      ),
      new MarkerLayerOptions(
        markers: [
          new Marker(
            width: 80.0,
            height: 80.0,
            point: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
            builder: (ctx) =>
            new Container(
              child: new FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a MapController (defined in your app) in your FlutterMap widget

```
MapController _mapctl = MapController();
...
void showFlutterMap(){
return new FlutterMap(
   mapController: _mapctl,
   ...
   );
 }
```

Then you have to move into the new location

```
latlng = LatLng(coordinates_you_want);
double zoom = 4.0; //the zoom you want 
_mapctl.move(latlng,zoom);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but in order to change the center of map in flutter_map you just need to change the values of center property of MapOptions. It's a **LatLng** object which accepts Latitude and Longitude.

```
  options: new MapOptions(
      center: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
      zoom: 13.0,
    ),
```